# How to sort file names in numerical order AND modified time order?

Tags: files, zsh, sort, pdf

I want to join pdf files by `pdfjoin`/`pdfunite`/... in the numerical order discussed well in the thread answer [linux command merge pdf files with numerical sort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23643544/54964) and *Modified* time order. 
If you use the solution in the thread, it puts the order in the numerical order and alphabetical order. 
This is problematic with the filenames such as where you see both have the same Modified time by minute accuracy but `Visceral` is earlier by second accuracy (File browser notes it and puts `Visceral` first in the `Modified` order.

```
Filename               Modified
-----                  ---
3.THE ABC.pdf          10:39 
3.Visceral abc..pdf    10:39
```

Complete filenames

```
1.Description abc.pdf
2.Gabcd.pdf
3.THE ABC.pdf
3.Visceral abc..pdf
4.description of abc.pdf
5.Chraa..pdf
```

Proposal #1 works in the numerical and alphabetical order but not in the numerical and modified order

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/23643544/54964
ls -v *.pdf | ...
    bash -c 'IFS=$'"'"'\n'"'"' read -d "" -ra x;pdfunite "${x[@]}" output.pdf'
```

Proposal #2 simplified case but does not deal whitespaces and other special characters in filenames

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/23643544/54964
pdfunite $(ls *.pdf | sort -n) output.pdf
```

There is nothing in the `pdfunite --help` about the ordering so I think it should be done by `ls`/`sort`/...
The command `sort` does not have anything about `modified` in its man page.

### Testing xhienne's answer

The order is not correct in the output where you see `2.jpg` and `4.jpg` are at the wrong order for some reason

```
masi@masi:~/Documents$ ls -tr /home/masi/Documents/[0-9]* | sort -t. -k1,1n -s
/home/masi/Documents/1.jpg
/home/masi/Documents/3.jpg
/home/masi/Documents/5.jpg
/home/masi/Documents/6.jpg
/home/masi/Documents/7.jpg
/home/masi/Documents/8.jpg
/home/masi/Documents/9.jpg
/home/masi/Documents/10.jpg
/home/masi/Documents/2.jpg
/home/masi/Documents/4.jpg
```

2nd iteration

```
export LC_ALL=C; ls -tr /home/masi/Documents/[0-9]* | sort -t. -k1,1n -s
```

Output

```
/home/masi/Documents/1.jpg
/home/masi/Documents/3.jpg
/home/masi/Documents/5.jpg
/home/masi/Documents/6.jpg
/home/masi/Documents/7.jpg
/home/masi/Documents/8.jpg
/home/masi/Documents/9.jpg
/home/masi/Documents/10.jpg
/home/masi/Documents/2.jpg
/home/masi/Documents/4.jpg
```

OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: Is is not clear to me whether you want an alphabetical/numerical sort, or a modification-time sort.

Comment: @xhienne I want AND of them. First numerical sort by the numbers in the prefix and then by modification-time sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do that with `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/stat

prefixmtime () {
sortstring=${(l:6::0:)${REPLY%%.*}}$(zstat -F '%s' +mtime -- $REPLY)
REPLY=${sortstring}
}

print -rl -- *(o+prefixmtime)
```

Replace `print -rl` with your command if you're happy with the result

---

How it works:
The globs will sort here (via [`o+function`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers)) based on what the function `prefixmtime` returns, that is `sortstring` which is a string obtained by concatenating the numerical prefix of each file name `${REPLY%%.*}` left-[padded](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) with zeros `(l:6::0:)` (assuming prefixes are up to 6-chars long) *and* the `mtime` in seconds (obtained via [`zstat`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fstat-Module) module). It may be easier to  understand how it works if you run:

```
{ for f (*)
printf '%s %s\n' ${(l:6::0:)${f%%.*}}$(zstat -F '%s' +mtime -- $f) $f
} | sort -k1,1n
```

Note that the above assumes you're in the same directory with your files, otherwise you'll have to define the sort string in that function as

```
sortstring=${(l:6::0:)${${REPLY##*/}%%.*}}$(zstat -F '%s' +mtime -- $REPLY)
```

and then you can use directory paths e.g.

```
print -rl some/place/else/*(o+prefixmtime)
```

Comment: How did you figured out `sortstring`? What is `*(o+prefixtime)` in Zsh? - - How is `zsh/stat` related to R?

Comment: @Masi - `o+function` is a glob qualifier, see link in my post. I'm having a hard time understanding your other questions.

Answer (score 4):

```
find /home/masi/Documents -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '[0-9]*' -printf "%T+ %f\n" | sort -k2n -k1,1| cut -d ' ' -f 2- | xargs -i echo pdfunite /home/masi/Documents/{} output.pdf
```

This will not handle new lines in filenames.

You can toggle reversing the sort orders by changing `-k1,1` to `-k1,1r` which will reverse the time sort and `-k2nr` will reverse the filename sort.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to first sort by modification time, then sort only on the first numerical field (assuming the fields are separated by '.') while disabling the last resort comparison (a.k.a. [stable sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort)).

```
ls -tr [0-9]* | sort -t. -k1,1n -s
```

[update]

Since you appear to have white-spaces in your filenames, you must use `xargs` to execute `pdfunite`:

```
ls -tr [0-9]* | ( sort -t. -k1,1n -s; echo output.pdf ) | xargs pdfunite
```

Comment: How to do expand this to cover whitespaces in filenames? See Proposal #1.

Comment: @Masi Use `xargs`. I have updated my answer with an example

Comment: Please, see the body. The first command has something wrong in it.

Comment: @Masi You might have a bizarre `locale` problem. Can you try `export LC_ALL=C` before my command?

Comment: Please, see the body for the output. - - So it does not help. My system is default 8.5 Debian.

Comment: @Masi Not a locale issue, it's simpler than that: You have added a path in front of the filenames. The whole path no longer starts with a number and the numerical sort can not operate properly. `cd` first to the "Documents" directory.

Comment: Yes, I use absolute paths. How can you query filename?