# Sort jpg according to creation date and convert to single pdf

Tags: shell, osx, sort, pdf, jpeg

On a Mac, how can I  sort about 2400 `jpg` according to their creation date (i. e. `stat -f %SB`) via terminal and convert them in that order into one pdf?

What if one `jpg` has been created today at 11:10 pm and a second one shortly after within the same minute at 11:10 pm? Are there seconds in the creation date, which can be taken into account?

Comment: You can do this easily with `zsh` (e.g. [custom sorting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332396)). I don't have access to OSX so cannot post an answer but this should be piece of cake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A simple command line with ImageMagick `convert` works for me.

I tested with the following command line (in a directory with 14 png files), and there will be one picture per page in the pdf file.

```
convert  *.png out-parrot.pdf
```

### But there can be problems with some versions of `convert`

**It works as intended with the version of `convert` in Parrot 4.4**

```
$convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101 https://imagemagick.org
```

**but it does not work with the version of `convert` in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS** (up to date in February 2019)

```
$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

This version is 'not authorized' to write pdf files

```
$ convert  *.png out-ubuntu.pdf
convert-im6.q16: not authorized `out-ubuntu.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.
```

---

```
$ apt-cache policy imagemagick
imagemagick:
  Installed: 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.4
  Candidate: 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.4
  Version table:
 *** 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.4 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

---

Via an Ubuntu mailing list I had the following answer (that converting to pdf was turned off because of problems with ImageMagick vulnerabilities)

> > Is this a bug in ImageMagick convert, specifically for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS,
> >     or is converting to pdf turned off by intention?
>
> The change was intentional. See https://usn.ubuntu.com/3785-1/
>
> Thanks, Jeremy Bicha

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the filesystem.  For example, on my host, I am using the fourth extended filesystem (ext4), and `stat` reports thusly for files:

```
$ touch foo; stat foo; rm foo
  File: 'foo'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fc00h/64512d    Inode: 262155      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   ownerusername)   Gid: ( 1000/   ownerusername)
Access: 2017-06-21 14:28:16.150323827 -0700
Modify: 2017-06-21 14:28:16.150323827 -0700
Change: 2017-06-21 14:28:16.150323827 -0700
 Birth: -
```

So you can use the last-modified time as [create time is something of a misnomer](https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=741616).

```
find /path/to/images -type f -print0 -name \*.jpg | xargs -0 stat -c "%y|%n" | sort | awk -F'|' '{print $2}'
```

This somewhat cumbersome construct will give you a list of files in order by last modification time (provided you have no files with `|` in their names).

Once you have and have reviewed this list, you can use Imagemagick's `convert` tool to assemble the PDF:

```
convert <<list of files>> outputfile.pdf
```

Or, to do it all at once:

```
convert $(find /path/to/images -type f -print0 -name \*.jpg | xargs -0 stat -c "%y|%n" | sort | awk -F'|' '{print $2}') outputfile.pdf
```

Comment: The OP mentions nothing about parsing exif data, however.

Comment: DopeGhoti, thank you very much your reply. When I try the above command I get the following error message `stat: illegal option -- c`. It is true, the picture I have do not have EXIF data.

Comment: Do you know which filesystem is in question here? `stat -c` works for me in my tests.

Comment: I might add that I want to use the above command on a Mac. I did not mentioned it before as I thought it would be irrelevant to the question. The filesystem would be `HFS Plus` or `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)`.

Comment: For a Mac, use `stat -f "%a|%N"`.

Comment: For me on my Mac only `stat -f %SB` did the work. However, adding this to the above script would not result in the desired pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Install ImageMagick. Assuming the JPG images are in `~/images` and the file names don't contain any spaces (nor any of `\[*?`) and you have a directory `~/combined`:

```
convert -combine -append $(ls -tr ~/images/*.jpg) ~/combined/all.jpg
```

or

```
  convert -combine -append $(ls -tr ~/images/*.jpg) ~/combined/all.pdf
```

If the images are not the same size, you will get warnings. `-append` combines images top to bottom. Change to `+append` and images will combine left to right.

Time: Although `ls -l` shows time down to hour:minute, Linux keeps track of the access, modify, and age/change times down to the nano second I believe. So sorting by `ls -tr` does account for even fractions of seconds.

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Thank you, Deathgrip, for answering. How can I convert the pictures into a single pdf as asked above?

Comment: @DopeGhoti - huh? the command works fine and I tested it using CentOS 7.

Comment: It will fail if any of those file names contains `[[:space:]]`...

Comment: Trying to parse the output of an `ls` is an exercise which, while it may seem to work, is a terribly bad habit to get into for many _many_ security-related reasons, which the link included in my answer goes into in great detail.  More detail can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls